# binary semaphore vs mutex

Tags: c++, mutex, semaphore

Imagine you have a double lock:

```
Ex:

mutex.lock();
mutex.lock();

Ex:

binarysemaphore.wait();
binarysemaphore.wait();
```

Would the behavior of these two differ?  Or would they be the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "double lock."  Do you mean "recursive mutex"?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean recursive lock (not double lock)

Whether the operation would be different depends wholly on the platform and implementation.

I think in windows the default is for Mutexes to be recursive (so reentrant lock works), and Semaphores are not.

However, on pthreads (POSIX) you can configure it any which way you prefer.

Comment: +1 for pointing out dependency on platform. If i remember correctly Posix does support a type of recursive mutex lock but it is not portable.

Comment: @Als: according to my man page (and [other sources](http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-gu.htm)), `pthread_mutexattr_gettype(PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE <or> PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL)` should be available; just `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` behaviour is undefined (i.e. platform dependent). It could be that I'm not aware of platforms with broken pthreads support

Answer (score 0):

During studies, we were told that `Semaphore` with `max count = 1` is equal to `Mutex`.

That is not entirely true.

1. `Mutex` can not be released by any other thread.
2. `Semaphore` can be used in such situation.